# How to escape equal = sign in VBS Shell command parameter

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, escaping, wsh

Using VBS on Windows 2012 R2 I am trying to pass a command line parameter `isActive="false"` but I cannot get the equal sign to appear in the command line.

Create a dummy batch file like test.bat

```
echo %1
Pause
```

Then in the created VBScript

```vb
 Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
 oShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\test"
 'strEqual = Chr(61)
 strCommand = "test.bat" & " " & "isActive=" &"""false"""
 return = oShell.Run(strCommand, 1, True)
 Set oShell = Nothing
```

I get *isActive "false"* but no equal sign.
I have tried separating out as a unique value
like `& Chr(61) &` and have tried escaping with `/` and `\` and `//` and `\\` before and after the equal sign. I have tried to use as a variable, `strEqual = Chr(61)`.

I am at a loss as to how to get the `=` to be part of the string when passed to the command shell. I can write it to a text file and the equal sign is written, but not in the shell.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that?, if you want to just pass arguments to the batch that isn't the way to do it. As a quick test, try running that command inside a Windows Command Prompt ( `test.bat isActive="false"`) yourself to see if it's doable before you add a VBScript into the mix.

Comment: Use `strCommand = "test.bat ""isActive=""false"""""` in VBScript and modify yout `test.bat` as `echo %~1`.

Comment: test.bat isActive="false" is proper for what I need.
The actual batch file is a differnt batch file but it requires the parameter as   isActive="false"

Comment: My command string is
    strCommand="dssetprop User-21 ""isActive=""false""""" 
and it returns
    dssetprop User-21 "isActive="false""  and fails becuase of the quotes around the string

Comment: Because you have stated that the CMD uses = as a delimiter is the reason I need to escape it so it ignores it as a delimiter and treats it as a character

Comment: @Hammertime so what you actually wanted was `test.bat "isActive="false""` in the command shell? Because if so, the question like many of your questions didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

You observe this behavior because CMD uses not only spaces and tabs, but also commas, semicolons, and the `=` character as [parameter delimiters](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters). Meaning that `isActive="false"` is parsed as 2 distinct arguments: `isActive` and `"false"`. If you want it to be parsed as a single argument you need to put the whole key/value pair in quotes: `"isActive=false"`.

Note that the double quotes inside VBScript string literals must be escaped by doubling them. If you require double quotes around the value part of the argument simply add another set of escaped double quotes.

```vb
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "test.bat ""isActive=""false"""""
return = oShell.Run(strCommand, 1, True)
```

There is also no need to concatenate string literals (except for readability reasons when you want to wrap a long string). Just define your command as a single string.

Comment: It will fail if I manually enter test.bat "isActive="false"" in the command window. I require it to read isActive="false" .

Comment: The final statement will be
test.bat User-21 isActive="false"  I get teh user from an Array. I have no problems in getting the command of
test.bat User-21
But the best I have been able to get is 
test.bat User-21 isActive "false"
the equal sign keeps getting dropped and is required.

Comment: Need the spaces to separate the parameters and the 2nd  parameter must be handed in as a value pair with quotes around the value

Comment: The above fails because I was working on another system and when I created the .bat file did not change the filename to test.bet. Is looks like JosefZ has the right syntax. Just checking now

Comment: @Hammertime If you require the nested double quotes around the value part of the argument you just need to add another set of escaped double quotes around that value.

Comment: Sorry the = sign drops out and is required. Without the = signit is just anotehr parameter and not a value pair. It writes the = sign into to a text file so it looks like there is no way to actually place the = sign into the command line via VBS script directly. I will need to write the command into a text file see if I can run the comand by reading the full line in the text file. The equal sign being a delimiter does not allow for escaping it out to use as text when sending to command line unless it sends quotes along with it.

Comment: I will now need to write the command to a text file and read the line from the file and use the readline as the command and hope that works

Comment: @Hammertime what are you talking about, how are you testing this? Ansgar's code will produce the command `test.bat "isActive="false""` if you run that direct in the Command Prompt what do you get? Your lack of ability to diagnose a problem in a methodical way is just staggering.

Comment: Yes "isActive="false"" will fail because of the outer quote marks This creates 1 parameter not a value pair. I need    `test.bat isActive="false"`

Comment: But the = sign drops of if there is not a visible quote before and after it in the command window. Passing it in any other fashion and the CMD removes it. That is my problem.  If you use `"isActive=" the equal sing is dropped, you could use """=""" and get "=" but the quote marks break the written batch file with an erro

Comment: @Lankymart - This is tested and used daily in the command window. I am trying to automate the process and if people could read they would see I specifically asked for 'isActive="false" not `"isActive="false"" in my original statement. If only people would read and if only I could type.

Comment: @Hammertime, In your bat file, use `echo %~1` instead of `echo %1`, which the former with `~` will remove the outer double quotes.

Comment: @michael_heath, that may be fine for my simple test batch file but does not work for the production batch file which is provided by another party. Where I cannot edit the batch file. But maybe I can create another batch file that does echo the command to a command window but I suspect I would run into the same issue again. Though worth investigating. ie the VBS sends the double quoted value pair to a middle batch file which echos the command as a run  command .

Comment: Ok, resolved by using VBS to send command with outer quotes to a batch file which echos the proper command to execute with %~1 removing the outer quotes and keeping the = sign

Comment: @Hammertime you might want to consider [omegastripe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329625/692942) before modifying the batch file.

Comment: @Lankymart How is that going to make a difference? If they can't change `%1` to `%~1` they won't be able to change it to `%myvar%` either.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers hey, not knocking your solution just like the elegance of omega's. Afterall, I did upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

You may pass a value from VBS to BAT/CMD using process environment variable.

Save the below code as test.vbs:

```
strCurDir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\"
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("process").Item("myvar") = "isActive=""false"""
CreateObject("WSCript.Shell").Run strCurDir & "test.bat"
```

And this code save as test.bat in the same folder:

```
echo %myvar%
pause
```

Run test.vbs and console output will be

> C:\Windows\system32>echo isActive="false"
> isActive="false"